# entity-framework not saving updates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-2.0

I am trying to update only a given number of columns in the table (as all do not need to be updated everytime).

So I would like to know using MVC entity-framework how this can be done.

I have tried what is below and I only want top update the subject title and description. Is this possible? **Currently this is not saving changes.**

```
var subjectInfo = db.subjects_tbl.SingleOrDefault(sub => sub.subject_id == model.subject_id);

subjectInfo.subject_title = model.subject_title;
subjectInfo.subject_description = model.subject_description

db.subjects_tbl.AddObject(subjectInfo);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: have you set AutoDetectChanges to false?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the state of `subjectInfo`

```
db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(subjectInfo,EntityState.Modified);
```

Do not use `addObject`. Change your code to

```
var subjectInfo = db.subjects_tbl.SingleOrDefault(sub => sub.subject_id == model.subject_id);

subjectInfo.subject_title = model.subject_title;
subjectInfo.subject_description = model.subject_description

db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(subjectInfo,EntityState.Modified);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: it making me add a method stub any ideas why

Comment: @user3636426, what do you mean method stub?

Comment: Change Entry to subjects_tbl as in your original query

Comment: @user3636426, I updated my answer to use the correct way for your version of entity framework

Comment: it stil doe not svae chnages

Comment: would this happen beuase there are other fileds in the database.

Comment: @user3636426, what do you mean it does not save? Does it give an exception?

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to modify the required properties and call `SaveChanges`:

```
var subjectInfo = db.subjects_tbl.SingleOrDefault(sub => sub.subject_id == model.subject_id);
if(subjectInfo != null) {
    subjectInfo.subject_title = model.subject_title;
    subjectInfo.subject_description = model.subject_description;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Don't call `AddObject` nor `ChangeObjectState` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use **AddObject** or **ChangeObjectState** in this case for update of table.

**Objects attached** to the object context are managed by that object context. The steps to update an existing entity are quite simple. First retrieve an instance of the entity from the **EntitySet** (in our case ObjectSet), then edit the properties of the Entity and finally call SaveChanges() on the context.

```
subjectInfo.subject_title = model.subject_title;
subjectInfo.subject_description = model.subject_description;
db.SaveChanges();
```